# So many unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a sequence of 12 numbers, each number after the first three is equal to the sum
of the previous three numbers.
The 3 rd number in the sequence is 6, the 6th number in the sequence is 11, and
the 11th number in the sequence is 14.
Determine all 12 numbers in the sequence

Comment: what have you tried? Because the first sentence gives you $9$ equations, the second bit gives you three, which is $12$ linear equations and $12$ unknowns, which is all you need to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Let the first three numbers be $a, b, c$ (where $c = 6$, but let's not focus on that just yet).

Then the sequence goes:

$a \\
b \\
c \\
a + b + c \\
b + c + (a + b + c) = a + 2b + 2c \\
c + (a + b + c) + (a + 2b + 2c) = 2a + 3b + 4c \\
(a + b + c) + (a + 2b + 2c) + (2a + 3b + 4c) = 4a + 6b + 7c \\
...$

Or, if we write each one as a triplet showing how many of each term contributes to it, then we get:

$(1, 0, 0) \\
(0, 1, 0) \\
(0, 0, 1) \\
(1, 1, 1) \\
(1, 2, 2) \\
(2, 3, 4) \\
(4, 6, 7) \\
(7, 11, 13) \\
(13, 20, 24) \\
(24, 37, 44) \\
(44, 68, 81) \\
(81, 125, 149)$

but don't quote me on that because I was doing that all in my head.

So you can just pick out the three of those terms that you need to solve everything, but as and added challenge I would suggest you consider what patterns there are in the numbers - for example, given $a, b, c$ is there a simple way for you to tell me the 100th term in the sequence?